# How can i disconnect in SignalR as my Mobile Data Connections gets off

Tags: android, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I had implemented ASP.NET SignalR with Android App. App works great but there is a problem. when i off the data connections, It takes time SignalR to disconnect the connection id created while onConnected() because it try to make connections till the time reach up to disconnection time it try to keep making connections, as a result the period of approx 1.5 min the app become useless.  which i don't want. I want if a connection gets break due to loss of connection should be disconnected immediately. Has anyone a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own method to stop the clients connection on such an event. You would probably use something similar to this

```
connection.hub.stop();
```

But if you really want the server to not wait you'll adjust the disconnect timeout, but if you do you'll have to adjust the keep-alive timeout accordingly if that was set manually.

**DisconnectTimeout**

[www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#disconnecttimeout](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#disconnecttimeout)

This setting represents the amount of time to wait after a transport connection is lost before raising the Disconnected event. The default value is 30 seconds. When you set DisconnectTimeout, KeepAlive is automatically set to 1/3 of the DisconnectTimeout value.

```
    // Wait a maximum of 30 seconds after a transport connection is lost
    // before raising the Disconnected event to terminate the SignalR connection.
    GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

Comment: I try to set disconnection timeout crackhaus but then signalR dont even make the connection and there is no method of calling a method if the android's dataconnection had been made OFF.

Comment: What did you set the disconnection timeout to?

Comment: I Set disconnection timeout to 3 and off the keepalive time.

Comment: you can't turn off the keep alive time unless you are doing long polling, Keep alive - This setting represents the amount of time to wait before sending a keepalive packet over an idle connection. The default value is 10 seconds. This value must not be more than 1/3 of the DisconnectTimeout value. so if you set disconnect timeout to 3 keep alive should be 1.

Comment: I am using Long pooling crackhaus. As i was getting some glitching while connecting with Android so i fall for the last one.

Comment: Ok, so you adjusted the disconnect timeout that'll shorten the amount of time it waits to throw disconnect event once the connection is lost. Since I know you are using long polling your client makes a connection and the server will listen for activity on that connection for a certain amount of time (ConnectionTimeout) and if nothing shows up it'll close the connection and then start a new one.

Comment: However you set the disconnect timeout to 3 seconds, so the new connection that it opens up has to happen before that 3 seconds or it fully disconnects. What's your connection timeout set to? By default it's 110 seconds so a minute 50, maybe that's why you are seeing that 1 and a half minute buffer. Anyway you can make the ConnectionTimeout shorter and leave the DisconnectTimeout and as long as the reconnect process can be made in under 3 seconds you're client will be able to reconnect but if there are intermittent connectivity issues you're client behavior will be spotty.